# why Form.useForm did not load the Component in react

Tags: reactjs

Now I am using this code to load a Login form, this is my code of the `Login` component:

```
class Login extends Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
           <div>dddddd</div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Form.useForm()(Login))
```

and this is my router define:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/login' render={(props) => <Login user={this.props.user} />}/>
                <Route path='/404' component={View404} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>)
    }
}
```

the antd version is `4.0.0` and the react version is `16.10.1`. why did not show the Login page? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `Form.useForm`, like this:

```
class Login extends Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
           <div>dddddd</div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Login)
```

works.